# Python function TypeError upon TkInter button click command

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror

I have the following code:

```
import mp3play
try:

    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:

    from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def playMusic(root):
    filename = r'D:\My Documents\School Work\A2 Computing\Project\Westerado.mp3'
    mp3 = mp3play.load(filename)
    mp3.play()

# Declaring the buttons
button1 = Button(text="Play", fg="Black", height=1, width=7, command= playMusic)
```

and some more which is irrelevant to this error, however when I run the program the GUI wil show up as normal, except that when I click `button1` I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python2.7\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: playMusic() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I have not done much work with Python functions and button commands and therefore am uncertain of what has gone wrong although I do believe that the function `playMusic` 's parameter(s) are incorrect.

What do I need to change here in order to get this working? I know that if I take out the `def playMusic(root):` altogether, then when I run to code the music will play as it should. But it is the button click command that is incorrect.

EDIT -

I have switched to def play_music():, now I do not get any error when I click the button. Instead, the program button will look like it has frozen being clicked down as if it is trying to do something but nothing will come of it.

Comment: `command`s don't get passed any arguments - switch to `def play_music():` (note also style-guide compliant name!)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have switched to `def play_music():`, now I do not get any error when I click the button. Instead, the program button will look like it has frozen being clicked down as if it is trying to do something but nothing will come of it.

Comment: I guess your `.play()` method never returns.

Comment: What is the code for mp3play?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The code for mp3play is: `import mp3play` `filename = r'D:\My Documents\School Work\A2 Computing\Project\Westerado.mp3'
    mp3 = mp3play.load(filename)
    mp3.play()` obviously the file path will differ for each person. The documentation for mp3play can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/mp3play/wiki/Examples

Comment: hmm `mp3play.play` should return immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I was playing around with the code to try and get something to work and I found that if I made this:

```
filename = r'D:\My Documents\School Work\A2 Computing\Project\Westerado.mp3'
mp3 = mp3play.load(filename)
```

global; and then within the function just have this:

```
def play_music():
    mp3.play()
```

then when I go to click the button "play" it works perfectly fine!

Not sure why this works and the other way did not! But right now I'm not complaining.

So overall it looks like:

```
filename = r'D:\My Documents\School Work\A2 Computing\Project\Westerado.mp3'
mp3 = mp3play.load(filename)

def play_music():
    mp3.play()

# Declaring the buttons
button1 = Button(text="Play", fg="Black", height=1, width=7, command=play_music)
```